# Find the range of $r_i$ given the inequality restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have a relationship
$$
\begin{cases}
0 \le r \le n \\
0 \le k_1 \le n_1,0 \le k_0 \le n_0\\
r=r_0+r_1\\
0 \le r_0 \le n_0\\
0 \le r_1 \le n_1
\end{cases}
$$
where $n=n_1+n_0,k_0,k_1,n_0$ are known

Could you help me to find the ranges of $r_i$, $i=\{ 0,1\}$ that satisfied each conditions

1. Find range of $r_0$ subject to $r_0 \ge k_0$
2. Find range of $r_1$ subject to $(r_1 \ge k_1) \cap (r_0 \ge k_0) $
3. Find range of $r_0$ subject to $(r_0 \ge k_0) \cup(r_1+r_0 \ge k_0+k_1) $
4. Find range of $r_1$ subject to $(r_1 \ge k_1) \cap (r_1+r_0 \ge k_0+k_1) $

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you by any chance miss $x$ in the $1. - 4.$ conditions?

Comment: The range of $x$ that means the space that satisfy each conditions. Sorry I mistaken

Comment: so you actually mean: find all $r_0, r_1$ such that $\dots$

Comment: Right. I corrected it. Let see it sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we remark the following. Since $0 \le r_0 \le n_0$, $0 \le r_1 \le n_1$, and  $n=n_1+n_0$, the condition $0 \le r \le n$ follows from the others so we may skip it. I shall assume that “where $n=n_1+n_0,k_0,k_1,n_0$ are known” means that $n=n_1+n_0$ and $k_0,k_1,n_0$ are known, but not necessarily $n$ is known. Thus the only unknown variables are $r_0 $, $r_1$, $r$,  $n_1$, and $n$.

1. We have $k_0\le r_0\le n_0$. It suffices to show that any value of $r_0$ from this interval can be achieved. For instance, for any  $k_0\le r_0\le n_0$ put $r_1=0$, $r=r_0$, $n_1=k_1$, and $n=n_0+n_1$. These values of the variables satisfy all given conditions.
2. We have $k_1\le r_1$. It suffices to show that any value of $r_1$ from this (unbounded) interval can be achieved. For instance, for any  $k_1\le r_1$ put $r_0=0$, $r=r_1$, $n_1=r_1$, and $n=n_0+n_1$. These values of the variables satisfy all given conditions.
3. We have $r_0\le n_0$. It suffices to show that any value of $r_0$ from this interval can be achieved. For instance, for any  $r_0\le n_0$ put $r_1=k_0+k_1$, $r=r_0+r_1$, $n_1=r_1$, and $n=n_0+n_1$. These values of the variables satisfy all given conditions.
4. We have $k_1\le r_1$. It suffices to show that any value of $r_1$ from this (unbounded) interval can be achieved. For instance, for any  $k_1\le r_1$ put $r_0=k_0$, $r=r_0+r_1$, $n_1=r_1$, and $n=n_0+n_1$. These values of the variables satisfy all given conditions.